# Change Dropbox folder location to a mounted network share?

Tags: dropbox

I would like to change the location of the Dropbox folder default location (/home/ben/Dropbox/) to that of a mounted cifs share /home/ben/nas

```
//192.168.0.14/dropbox  /home/ben/nas  cifs etc etc
```

I seem to get an error when using the GUI after choosing my desired location.

Is this possible?